# ExtentReports: detachReporter() method

Tags: extentreports, extent, selenium-extent-report

I am using a suite file with multiple suites inside the `testng.xml` file as follows:

```
<suite-files>
        <suite-file path="suite1"></suite-file>
        <suite-file path="suite2"></suite-file>
</suite-files>
```

I am initializing `ExtentReport` in `BeforeSuite`.

```
private static void initializeExtentReport(Configuration config) {
        if (extent == null) {
            extent = new ExtentReports();
            htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("reportLocation");
            ClassLoader classLoader = ExtentReportService.class.getClassLoader();
            File extentConfigFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("extent-config.xml").getFile());
            htmlReporter.loadXMLConfig(extentConfigFile);
            extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
            extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", config.getAutomationServer());
        }
    }
```

In `AfterSuite`, I am calling `flush()`.

So basically the issue is, when the before suite is called for the second suite, The check (`extent==null`), is coming false. I also went through the `JavaDocs` for `ExtentReports` and I found a method `detachReporter()` there. But I am not able to access by my IDE. Tried many variations but to no fruition.

EDIT:

Right now what really happens is, I am using custom names for reports, so that no two report names are the same. And, when I was using with the same name, the results would be over written in the same file for the suites.

Comment: Why you need to check condition (extent == null) ?

Comment: I am using this condition to make sure that every time any suite runs, a new instance is created.

Comment: There is no need to check instance for Extent Report. Once you are define initialization for extent report it can create two reports in single method. So you don't need it.

Comment: Tried it, but the flush() call is not executed, i,.e it s not throwing any exception after executing.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach here is to use a singleton like so:

```
public class Extent 
    implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static class ExtentReportsLoader {

        private static final ExtentReports INSTANCE = new ExtentReports();

        static {
        }
    }

    public static synchronized ExtentReports getInstance() {
        return ExtentReportsLoader.INSTANCE;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private ExtentReports readResolve() {
        return ExtentReportsLoader.INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
ExtentReports extent = Extent.getInstance();
```

So your code becomes:

```
private static void initializeExtentReport(Configuration config) {
    extent = Extent.getInstance();
    if (extent.getStartedReporters().isEmpty()) {
        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("reportLocation");
        ClassLoader classLoader = ExtentReportService.class.getClassLoader();
        File extentConfigFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("extent-config.xml").getFile());
        htmlReporter.loadXMLConfig(extentConfigFile);
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
        extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", config.getAutomationServer());
    }
}
```

I would further recommend getting rid of all shared variables for extent/htmlReporter and directly use the Singleton

Comment: I have another question, when we initialize extent value, which is static, for the first suite, will it be removed after suite is executed? Also, new report is not created when the htmlReporter instance is being called.